# Members vs method arguments access in C++

Tags: c++, class, methods, arguments, instance

Can I have a method which takes arguments that are denoted with the same names as the members of the holding class? I tried to use this:

```
    class Foo {
        public:
            int x, y;
            void set_values(int x, int y)
            {
                x = x;
                y = y;
            };
    };
```

... but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way of accessing the the instance the namespace of which I'm working in, similar to JavaScript's `this` or Python's `self`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to avoid this kind of confusion by using a naming convention for member variables.  For example, camelCaseWithUnderScore_ is quite common.  That way you would end up with `x_ = x;`, which is still a bit funny to read out loud, but is fairly unambiguous on the screen.

If you *absolutely need* to have the variables and arguments called the same, then you can use the `this` pointer to be specific:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        int x, y;
        void set_values(int x, int y)
        {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        }
};
```

By the way, note the trailing semi-colon on the class definition -- that is needed to compile successfully.

Comment: Avoid _ . See this note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Comment: Actually, avoid starting an identifier with _ - ending it with _ is fine and quite common.

Comment: @MartinYork: @Bojan Resnik is correct. Also, I believe decorating member variables with a trailing _ is endorsed by Herb Sutter.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should be able to write this using the "this" keyword (which is a pointer in C++):

```
class Foo {
    public:
        int x, y;
        void set_values(int x, int y)
        {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `C++` the current instance is referenced by the `const` pointer `this`.

```
class Foo {
    public:
        int x, y;
        void set_values(int x, int y)
        {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
        };
};
```